# what do you call this type of navigation?

Tags: php, html

may seem to be a small question but can any one tell me what is this strip on the top called?

The one above the heading and below the menu and has a navigation arrow on the left and right... what to use to make it

http://arabia.msn.com/news/entertainment/entertainment-music/1112010/britney-spears-splits-from-fiance/

Comment: Are you talking about the slider with the images?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic

Comment: @relentless yes the images one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a simple script that called
[jCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_simple.html). More examples [here](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/#Examples)

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is called a slider or image gallery. Do a search "jQuery image slider" and you'll find a ton